# How to create sequential number column in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, sequential-number

I would like to create column with sequential numbers in **pyspark** dataframe starting from specified number. For instance, I want to add column **A** to my dataframe **df** which will start from **5** to the length of my dataframe, incrementing by one, so **5**, **6**, **7**, ..., *length*(**df**).

Some simple solution using **pyspark** methods?

Comment: Easiest way is probably `df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF(cols + ["index"]).withColumn("index", f.col("index") + 5)` where `cols = df.columns` and `f` refers to `pyspark.sql.functions`. But you should ask yourself why you're doing this, bc almost surely there's a better way. DataFrames are inherently unordered, so this operation is not efficient.

Comment: Thank you! At the end I want to add the final results to Hive table. I have to take max(id) from this table and add new records with id starting from max(id) + 1.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to get a serial id column in Hive like that. Hive/Spark is intended for parallel processing. Even though the code in my comment works for you and you may be able to come up with a way to achieve your desired result, this is not really a good use case for spark or hive.

Comment: I handled it by adding new column to my df like this: `max(id) + spark_func.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(unique_field_in_my_df)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using **range**

```
df_len = 100
freq =1
ref = spark.range(
    5, df_len, freq
).toDF("id")
ref.show(10)

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
| 10|
| 11|
| 12|
| 13|
| 14|
+---+
```

only showing top 10 rows

Comment: The question is to add a "new" column to an existing dataframe

Answer (score 5):

Three simple steps:

from pyspark.sql.window import Window

from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id,row_number

df =df.withColumn("row_idx",row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))

Answer (score 2):

Although the question was asked long time ago, I though I could share my solution which I found very convenient.
Basically to add a column of 1,2,3,... you can simply add first a column with constant value of 1 using "lit"

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window    
df= df.withColumn("Id", func.lit(1))
```

Then apply a cumsum (unique_field_in_my_df is in my case a date column. Probably you can also use the index)

```
windowCumSum = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('unique_field_in_my_df').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
df = df.withColumn("Id",func.sum("Id").over(windowCumSum))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This creates sequential value into the column.

```
seed = 23
df.withColumn('label', seed+dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('column')))
```

Comment: Does it require data to be in same partition ?