# PySpark add Id column & Filter broken

Tags: pyspark

I've got a data set with currently 233,465 rows and growing by approximately 10,000 rows daily.  I need to randomly select rows from the full data set for usage in ML training.  I've added an "id" column for the "index".

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
spark_df = n_data.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

I execute the following code expecting to see 5 rows returned where the id's match the "indices" list with a count of 5.

```
indices = [1000, 999, 45, 1001, 1823, 123476]
result = spark_df.filter(col("id").isin(indices))
result.show()
print(result.count())
```

instead, I get 3 rows.  I get the ids for 45, 1000 and 1001.

Any ideas on what might be wrong here?  This seems pretty cut and dry.

Thanks!

Comment: [monotonically_icreasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) produces unique but not consecutive numbers. Rows with 123476, 1823 and 999 simply doesn't exist in your dataframe.

Comment: Check the comments of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200217/how-to-create-sequential-number-column-in-pyspark-dataframe) for examples to assign a sequential number.

Comment: ah, lame.  I guess that would explain the behavior I am getting.

Comment: any idea how to do a mydf.withColumn("id", spark.range(0, n_data.count(), 1)); I try wrapping in column, col, .toDF() and get various errors accross that gambit.

Comment: That doesn't work because spark doesn't know how to assign the values. Just follow the comments (not the answers) of that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200217/how-to-create-sequential-number-column-in-pyspark-dataframe).

Comment: I ended up solving my problem differently using sample which achieved my end goal.  I'll keep as open question; because this would be cool to know how to do anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct function to call to assign unique, sequential IDs to each row. But there's workaround using `window`-based function.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(3,),(7,),(9,),(1,),(-3,),(5,)], ["values"])
df.show()

+------+
|values|
+------+
|     3|
|     7|
|     9|
|     1|
|    -3|
|     5|
+------+



df = (df.withColumn('dummy', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
       .withColumn('ID', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('dummy')))
       .drop('dummy'))
df.show()

+------+---+
|values| ID|
+------+---+
|     3|  1|
|     7|  2|
|     9|  3|
|     1|  4|
|    -3|  5|
|     5|  6|
+------+---+
```